# Node.js idiomatic constructor argument checking

Tags: node.js, constructor

What is the idiomatic way to check for the presence of required constructor function arguments?

Example:

```
    module.exports = function MyCtorFn (param1, ...) {

      function init() {
         if(param1 == null) {
           throw "param1 not supplied.";
         }
      }

      //...

      init();
    };
```

Comment: Depends on what value is allowed. Your example will disallow `null` and `undefined`. Sometimes you may want to allow `null` if it can be explicitly passed in as a value.

Comment: Thank you. I am not asking about the check itself, but the way of checking. Is the addition of an init function and the immediate invocation of it as above idiomatic?

Comment: Oh I see. No, I would say it's not. Why do you need it? Why not just do the checks in the constructor itself?

Comment: So the idiomatic approach would be directly in the ctor? `module.exports = function MyCtorFn (param1) { if(param1 == null) { ...         } ... }`?

Comment: I would say so, yes. But there are not really any conventions around this specific behaviour so I would also say just do it the way that works best for you.

Comment: OK, thanks. I find checking for the presence of arguments to make troubleshooting easier because things fail faster.

Comment: Agreed, it's definitely good practice to check that the arguments are valid. I just mean there's not really any conventions around how/where those checks take place. I would just put them straight in the constructor.

Comment: `assert.notEqual(param1, null)` ?